# C++ catch block is not catching exception

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

The following code is still crashing instead of having try-catch block. I use the g++ compiler on Window 10.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int top = 90;
    int bottom = 0;

    try
    {
        cout << "top / 2 = " << (top / 2) << endl;

        cout << "top divided by bottom = ";
        cout << (top / bottom) << endl;

        cout << "top / 3 = " << (top / 3) << endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "something has gone wrong!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Done." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        throw 0;
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Exception occured"! << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This one works fine. I mean the catch block here catches the thrown exception.

Comment: why do you expect an exception in the first code ?

Comment: you need to learn about [undefined beahvior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). In C++ unlike in other languages you are assumed to know what you are doing. It doesnt hold your hand, if you want to shoot yourself in your foot it says: go ahead and do it

Comment: It’s like when [your boomerang won’t come back](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_prtbj4MtDU) — first you have to throw it.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 — because the OS announced that there was an exception.